# Remove Matlab r2014b Plot Browser limit

Tags: matlab

Among many distressing graphics changes to r2014b, the Plot Browser now only displays a certain number of lines per plot (looks like the limit is 50).  Any number of plots above this limit are not displayed in the Plot Browser - it just says "and 78 more..."

Is there anyway to remove the limit?  I want to see all my lines in the plot browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is currenty:

### No you cannot remove this limit

This was [already reported to mathworks a while ago](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/161404-how-can-i-browse-a-large-amount-of-curves-in-plotbrowser-r2014b), and here is the reply:

> I am writing in reference to your Technical Support Case #01143663
> regarding 'plot browser with "and xxxx more...." indication'.
>
> Really interesting question (and even a bit surprising). Basically
> this limitation has been introduced with MATLAB 2014b!
>
> Our developers are aware of that, and they are working to solve it. An
> enhancement/bug request has been already submitted, and I am going to
> add this case to the list. However, I cannot guarantee you a release
> date.
>
> If you think this limitation is crucial for your work, I would
> strongly suggest you to contact your account manager, which will have
> a bit more influence on the developers than a simple engineer :).
>
> Of course, if there is anything else I can do for you, please let me
> know

So it seems that you will have to deal with this limitation if you keep using 2014b.

Answer (score 0):

This was also an issue for me; in particular I wanted to see the DisplayName property of the graphics object in the list.  I used a workaround where I created a callback function, so that when clicking on a data point, the DisplayName would be shown.  This can be helpful if you have a plot of many lines and want to see the DisplayName of a particular one.  You would first need to set the DisplayName property of the graphics objects for this to work, as it's empty by default.  You could also use this to show other properties, such as Color or LineStyle, that are shown in the plot browser:

```
%Based on
%http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html
%'fig_h' is the figure handle
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig_h);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)
```

And then include this function as a separate file on the Matlab path, or paste into the function you're currently writing, and include an extra 'end' at the end of that function:

```
function name = myupdatefcn(empt,event_obj)
% Customizes text of data tips
tar = get(event_obj,'Target');
name = get(tar,'DisplayName');
end
```